# Inkness theme sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am using the inkness theme for my site, mostly it works fine apart form when I try to remove all of the widgets from the sidebar. When I do this the widgets for the archive, search and meta automatically appear. These widgets are not added to the sidebar but they still appear on the site regardless.
I tried getting an answer for this on the forum on Inkhive but I haven't got a response yet. I'm hoping someone here has come across this type of problem (and knows how to fix it!) with this theme before.

Comment: This is expected behavior. If you use `dynamic_sidebar` and there is no single widget in your sidebar, WordPress loads the/a default sidebar. If you don't need/want to have widgets (i.e., a sidebar at all), you might want to customize the theme...

Comment: Questions that are too localized (such as syntax errors, themes and code with restricted access, hacked sites, hosting or support issues) are not in scope. See how do I ask a good question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok cheers for that